# What does a typedef with parenthesis like "typedef int (f)(void)" mean? Is it a function prototype?

Tags: c, typedef

```
typedef int (fc_name) (void);
```

Here `fc_name` is any valid C symbol.

How different is this from a function pointer `typedef`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's a `typedef` to a function type.  The intent is to use it for function pointers, but in this case the syntax to use it would be:

```
int bar(void);

fc_name* foo = bar; /* Note the * */
```

Update:
As mentioned in the comments to [Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3674225/179715), the `typedef` can be used to declare functions.  One use could be for declaring a set of callback functions:

```
typedef int (callback)(int, void*);

callback onFoo;
callback onBar;
callback onBaz;
callback onQux;
```

Comment: +1: Ah - so that's how it gets to be useful!  I've demonstrated that you're correct - but only once you showed me how.  We live, we learn; SO rocks.

Comment: I suppose you'd still have to include the whole function prototype for every function definition? EDIT: Never mind [Jonathan Leffler's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3674225/388916) addressed that.

Answer (score 23):

The first parentheses are superfluous - it is equivalent to:

```
typedef int fc_name(void);
```

<s>I don't think this does anything useful, though I can't get GCC to complain about it on its own.</s>

This means that `fc_name` is an alias for a function type that takes no arguments and returns an `int`. It isn't directly all that useful, though you can declare, for example, the `rand()` function using:

```
fc_name rand;
```

You cannot use the `typedef` in a function definition.

A pointer to function typedef would read:

```
typedef int (*fc_name)(void);
```

---

This code shows that the typedefs without the asterisk are not function pointers (addressing a now-deleted alternative answer):

```
static int function(void)
{
    return 0;
}

typedef int   fc_name1 (void);
typedef int  (fc_name2)(void);
typedef int (*fc_name3)(void);

fc_name1 x = function;
fc_name2 y = function;
fc_name3 z = function;
```

When compiled, 'gcc' says:

```
gcc -Wextra -Wall -pedantic -c -O x.c
x.c:10:1: error: function ‘x’ is initialized like a variable
x.c:11:1: error: function ‘y’ is initialized like a variable
```

---

And this code demonstrates that you can indeed use `fc_name *var = funcname;` as suggested by [jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin):

```
static int function(void)
{
    return 0;
}

typedef int   fc_name1 (void);
typedef int  (fc_name2)(void);
typedef int (*fc_name3)(void);

fc_name1  x_0 = function;
fc_name1 *x_1 = function;
fc_name2  y_0 = function;    // Damn Bessel functions - and no <math.h>
fc_name2 *y_1 = function;    // Damn Bessel functions - and no <math.h>
fc_name3  z   = function;
```

Using y0, y1 generates GCC warnings:

```
x.c:12:11: warning: conflicting types for built-in function ‘y0’
x.c:13:11: warning: built-in function ‘y1’ declared as non-function
```

---

And, building on the comment from [schot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251122/schot):

```
static int function(void)
{
    return 0;
}

typedef int   fc_name1 (void);
typedef int  (fc_name2)(void);
typedef int (*fc_name3)(void);

fc_name1  x_0 = function;   // Error
fc_name1 *x_1 = function;   // x_1 is a pointer to function
fc_name1  x_2;              // Declare int x_2(void);
fc_name1 *x_3 = x_2;        // Declare x_3 initialized with x_2

fc_name2  y_0 = function;   // Damn Bessel functions - and no <math.h>
fc_name2 *y_1 = function;   // Damn Bessel functions - and no <math.h>
fc_name1  y_2;              // Declare int y_2(void);
fc_name1 *y_3 = x_2;        // Declare y_3 initialized with y_2

fc_name3  z   = function;
```

Interesting - the dark corners of C are murky indeed.

Comment: Some people prefer the typedef to be of the function signature pre-pointer-taking. That shifts the "explictness" of taking a pointer to the declaration of each function pointer. It's a matter of style, I think.

Comment: You can also use a function `typedef` for a function *declaration* (prototype), but not for a *definition*. But this is not very useful, except for obfuscation.

Comment: @schot: Neat, I didn't know it could be used for function declarations.  I actually do think that is kind of useful for declaring a set of callback functions; previously I was using a preprocessor macro to simplify that.

Answer (score 2):

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 
  3 
  4 typedef int (fc_name)(void);
  5 
  6 
  7 
  8 int test_func1 ()
  9 {
 10     printf("\n test_func1 called\n");
 11 
 12     return 0;
 13 }
 14 
 15 int test_func2 (void)
 16 {
 17     printf("\n test_func2 called\n");
 18     return 0;
 19 }
 20 
 21 int handler_func(fc_name *fptr)
 22 {
 23     //Call the actual function
 24     fptr();
 25 }
 26 
 27 int main(void)
 28 {
 29     fc_name  *f1, *f2;
 30 
 31     f1 = test_func1;
 32     f2 = test_func2;
 33 
 34     handler_func(f1);
 35     handler_func(f2);
 36 
 37     printf("\n test complete\n");
 38 
 39     return 0;
 40 }
```

OUTPUT:-

```
 test_func1 called

 test_func2 called

 test complete
```

---

So the typedef which I questioned about, (Line # 4 here) represents a 
function type and is not the same as function pointer typedef.
This kind of typedef does not have much significance. These are used as a 
style standard or simply to create obfuscation intentionally ;-)

Comment: Note that you could use: `int handler_func2(fc_name fptr)
{
    return fptr();
}` because the 'function' parameter is automatically treated as (converted to) a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting! A typedef declaration is a declaration with typedef as the storage class.

```
typedef int   fc_name1 (void);   
// this defines a function type called fc_name1 
// which takes no parameter and returns int
```

later on, you could define a function like following,

```
fc_name1 myFunc;
// this is equivalent to the next line
// int myFunc(void);
```

You should be able figure this out from the c/c++ standard!

Answer (score 1):

I've never before seen this done to a *typedef name*, but parentheses around the name of a *function* are useful to prevent its being expanded as a function-like macro of the same name.  For instance, the `isxxx` functions in `ctype.h` are defined as both functions and macros.  This is so you can take a pointer to `isalpha`.  But how does the C library *define* the out-of-line `isalpha`?  Probably like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int
(isalpha)(int c)
{
    return isalpha(c);
}
```

The use of `isalpha` in the function body is expanded as a macro, the use in the function header isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is:

```
typedef int (*myfunc)(void);
```

You can define a function like follows:

```
int helloword(void) {
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

and then define a variable point to this function:

```
myfunc hw_func;
hw_func = helloworld;
```

and call the function by the function pointer:

```
int ret = (*hw_func)();
```

The reason we need function pointer is that C language doesn't have predefined function pointer and use `void *` pointer to call a function is illegal in C language.