# C "function pointer" typedef without asterisk?

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does this typedef mean? a function prototype ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674200/what-does-this-typedef-mean-a-function-prototype)

Today I came across this syntax

```
typedef double (d2d)(double);
```

[cdecl tells me](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=double+%28f%29%28double%29%3B) it's a function returning a double (as opposed to a pointer to a function returning a double). So let's see how it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef double (d2d)(double);
//typedef double (*d2d)(double); // the "usual" way

double twice(double x)
{
    return x * 2.0;
}

double apply(d2d f, double x)
{
    return f(x);
}


int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", apply(twice, 2.0)); // Prints 4.0000
    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, GCC 4.2.1 compiled it without problems. I'm just curious to know what are the subtle differences between this and the "usual" way to `typedef` a function pointer?

Comment: In this context, functions decay to pointers to functions, just like arrays decay to pointers to their first element in many contexts. See 6.3.2.1/4; 6.5.2.2/1; 6.5.2.2/5; 6.7.5.3/6; in the Standard.

Comment: typedef double d2d(double); should do as well.

Comment: Note that some people consider array and function type typedefs harmful because they "decay" to a completely different type in function arguments, and thereby become difficult to use as an opaque type (you need to be aware of this decay to use the type safely in certain situations).

Comment: Thanks for the "answers", though I don't agree that this is an "exact" duplicate. I should mention that I have already read that question. The main part of this question is **what are the subtle differences between this and the "usual" way to typedef a function pointer?** The referred "duplicate" does not mention function _decyaing_ to function pointers when used as arguments (all of its examples use the `typedef` as a local variable). And I believe my question title is a lot more SEO friendly :P