# Strange typedef to function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, types, compiler-errors, typedef

I am using a code written by somebody else, where they intend to use a function pointer. They do a very strange typdef that I can not understand. Below the code

```
typedef void (myType)(void);
typedef myType *myTypePtr;
```

I can understand that the main idea with `myTypePtr` is to create a "pointer to a function that receives void and returns void. But what about the original `myType`? What is that? a function type? Is not clear to me.

Furthermore, later there is this function prototype

```
int createData(int id,int *initInfo, myTypePtr startAddress)
```

However I get the compile error "expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'myTypePtr' any idea why this is happening?. Thank you very much.

Comment: With the two typedefs in scope, it ought to compile (if you add a semicolon or function body), and it does here. Can you create a small test case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does this typedef mean? a function prototype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674200/what-does-this-typedef-mean-a-function-prototype)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This first `typedef`

```
typedef void (myType)(void);
```

provides `myType` as a synonym for the type `void (void)`, the type of a function that takes no arguments and returns `void`.  The parentheses around `myType` aren't actually necessary here; you could also write

```
typedef void myType(void);
```

to make it clearer that it's the type of a function that takes `void` and returns `void`.  Note that you can't actually declare any variables of function type; the only way to get an object of function type in C is to define an actual function.

The second `typedef`

```
typedef myType *myTypePtr;
```

then says that `myTypePtr` has a type that's equal to a pointer to a `myType`, which means that it's a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns `void`.  This new type is equivalent to the type `void (*)(void)`, but is done a bit indirectly.

As for your second error, I can't say for certain what's up without more context.  Please post a minimal test case so that we can see what's causing the error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I solved the compilation problem, I was not including other necessary files, in any case, thank you for answering the meaning of the first typedef, it was really unusual and I was surprised by it. Thank you again.