# understanding typedefs for functions in C

Tags: c, typedef

I came across the following function  declaration and I am not able to understand how exactly it works:
the function is declared in the file as follows:

```
struct newtype {
  /* some definition */
};

typedef void function1 (int* a, newtype* p);
```

then in another C code above declaration is used to declare another function2 as follows:

```
function1 function2;

void function2(int* a, newtype* p)
{ 
  /* function definition */  
}
```

Then function2 is used as follows:

```
int function3 (int, char, function1* );

/* definition */
function3(int a, char c, function2 )
{ 
  /* function definition */
}
```

I am not able to understand the statement:
function1 function2; 
and what does typedef void function1 (arguments) mean as function1 is not declared as a pointer. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: I can't get this code to compile...

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does this typedef mean? a function prototype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674200/what-does-this-typedef-mean-a-function-prototype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function1 is declared as a type for functions not returning anything and taking a pointer to an int and a pointer to a newtype as arguments.

This way is useful to make sure you get functions that conform to a particular format especially when you use callback functions / function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 typedef void function1 (int* a, newtype* p);
```

defines the name *function1* as an alias for the type `void ()(int *, newtype *)` i.e. a function.

Thus `function1 function2;` is the same as this prototype:

```
void function2 (int* a, newtype* p);
```

The name `function1` could also be used to declare a pointer, which result in a familiar "function pointer". That is what function3 is doing when it declares `int function3 (int, char, function1* );` - its last argument is a pointer to a function with the signature `void ()(int *, newtype *)`