# Is an asterisk optional in a function pointer?

Tags: c, function

The code I am using has this statement:

```
typedef void  ( udp_data_notify )(OS_FIFO * pfifo, WORD port);
```

This looks like a declaration of a function pointer for udp_data_notify, however there is no `*`. Can it still be a function pointer without an asterisk?

Here is a statement that uses `udp_data_notify`:

```
void RegisterUDPFifoWithNotify( WORD dp, OS_FIFO *pnewfifo , udp_data_notify * nudp)
```

Any help as to what is happening would be appreciated!

Comment: Dereferencing a function pointer could technically produce the first byte of the first machine code instruction of the function.  Big question is what you'd want to do with that in a portable way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a typedef with parenthesis like "typedef int (f)(void)" mean? Is it a function prototype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674200/what-does-a-typedef-with-parenthesis-like-typedef-int-fvoid-mean-is-it-a)

Answer (score 6):

A typedef such as:

```
typedef void name(int);
```

(the parenthesis around `name` are redundant) will define `name` as the type of a function, not a function pointer. That would be:

```
typedef void (*pname)(int);
```

You are probably wondering what they are good for. Well, function types are not very useful, other than for declaring pointers:

```
name *pointer_to_function;
```

And that can be made arguably more readable with the other typedef:

```
pname pointer_to_function;
```

That's because you cannot define a variable of type function. If you try, you will simply write the prototype of a function, but in a quite obfuscated syntax:

```
name foo;   //declaration (prototype), not variable
void foo(int x) //definition
{
}
```

But note that you cannot use the typedef to define the function:

```
name foo {} //syntax error!
```

Comment: "function types are not very useful? Are there any cases in which it is useful?

Comment: @onmyway133: Not that I know of. Unless you count obfuscation as useful.

Comment: I hear many people state that the "non asterisk declaration" is automatically converted to "asterisk declaration",

Comment: @onmyway133: See the answer below by Timo. AFAIK, that automatic conversion is done only with function parameter declarations, but not with normal variables (locals or globals). This only adds to the confusion, and it is another reason to not use non-pointer function types.

Comment: @onmyway133 One useful case is to put the function declaration in a macro (one that accepts a variable for the type name), and then `typedef MACRO(function_type);`  Next, you can define an actual function using `MARCO(FunctionName) { }` without raising a syntax error.  And finally, you can declare and define function pointers with `function_type *f = FunctionName;`  Casey Muratori]did this [on his stream](https://hero.handmade.network/episode/code/day006/) to create function stubs in case an extern function wasn't available. (approx. at the 23 minute mark in the video link)

Answer (score 4):

As already said, the typedef declares an alias for function type. When you want to use it to declare a function pointer, an asterisk is required (`udp_data_notify* x`). A declaration without the asterisk (`udp_data_notify x`) would be a function declaration, except in one special case. When used in a parameter a function type is automatically turned into the corresponding function pointer type:

```
typedef void F(void);
void foo(F a, F* b) // special case; a and b are both function pointers
{
    F c; // function declaration
    F* d; // function pointer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `typedef` you show declares `udp_data_notify` to be an alias for a function type. Then the parameter declaration `udp_data_notify *nudp` declares `nudp` to be a pointer to a function of that type. There is no function call here.

Regarding the function-call operator (postfix `()`), the expression that designates the called function must be a pointer to a function. When you call a function normally, without a pointer, such as `sqrt(2)`, the function is automatically converted to a pointer for you. So `sqrt(2)` is actually `(&sqrt)(2)`. When you call a function with a pointer, the call is in the right form already.

Comment: The function being converted to a pointer there is new C99 behavior I believe. In C89 and K&R, with implicit functions, the non-parenthesized form `f()` for functions calls seems to actually have been a special case. Note that `(f)()` is invalid if `f` is not declared, even in C89.