# C function name or function pointer?

Tags: c, function-pointers

Let's see this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*callback) (void *arg);
callback world = NULL;

int f(void *_) {
    printf("World!");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    printf("Hello, ");
    // world = f;
    world = &f; // both works
    if (world != NULL) {
        world(NULL);
    }
}
```

When setting `world` variable, both
`world = f;` and `world = &f;` works.

Which should I use? Does it depend on the compiler or C version?

```
% gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293403/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-function-when-passed-as-a

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674200/what-does-a-typedef-with-parenthesis-like-typedef-int-fvoid-mean-is-it-a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `world = f;` and `world = &f;` works because there is no difference between `f` and `&f` when passing it as an argument.

See [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) specification (section 6.7.5.3.8).

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `f` is of type `int (void *_)`. Whenever `f` is used in an expression, it is implicitly converted to a pointer to itself, which is of type `int(*) (void *_)`.

> Which should I use?

So, for all practical purposes, the name of a function `f` and a pointer to the same function `&f` are interchangeable. Also have a look at  ["Why do all these function pointer definitions all work? "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893285/why-do-function-pointer-definitions-work-with-any-number-of-ampersands-or-as)

> Does it depend on the compiler or C version?

Not depend on any compiler or C version.