# C++ pointer to function declaration syntax

Tags: c++, function-declaration

What is the difference between the two declarations in case of `foo`'s arguments? The syntax in the second one is familiar to me and declares a pointer to function. Are both declarations fully equivalent?

```
void foo(int(int));
void foo(int(*)(int));
```

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3674225/65863) has some useful information about the use of, and lack of, an asterisk in function pointer declarations.

Comment: Also see: [Is the non-pointer syntax for declaring function pointer parameters not worth mentioning?](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/07/is-non-pointer-syntax-for-declaring.html)

Comment: gcc thinks that they are equal in this context: https://ideone.com/snKfj6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are equivalent as long as `int(int)` and `int(*)(int)` are used in function parameter lists. In function parameter list the `int(int)` is automatically *adjusted* by the language to mean `int(*)(int)`.

It is the same [adjustment mechanism](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5) that makes `int []` parameter declaration equivalent to `int *` parameter declaration.

Outside of this specific context `int(int)` and `int(*)(int)` mean two different things.

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate on what are the two different meanings of the delcaration outside of function parameter context? Do you mean that one declares a function type and the other a pointer? I.e. something that has already been pointed out in the comments to my question?